# XAMPP, VS Code, PHP, Windows. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "Chislo", expecting "," or ";" on line 5

Tags: php, apache, visual-studio-code, xampp

Задание: Скрипт проверяет, является ли введённое число — целым числом.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang= "ru">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Проверка целосчисленности значения </title>
</head>
<body>
        <form name="8" action="3 (8).php" method ="POST">
        <label> Введите своё число: </label> <br/>
        <input type = "text" name= "Chislo"> <br/>
        <input type = "submit" name= "Gotovo" value= "Нажми"/>
        </form>

</body>
</html>

<HEAD>
```

Результат HTML:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PHP:

```
<?php

if (is_int($_POST ["Chislo"]))
{
    echo "Ответ: ($_POST ["Chislo"])";
}
?>
```

Результат PHP:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее указан путь, который верно указал. Проверял несколько раз. И в итоге номер линии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ошибку прочитали? Осмыслили? Что она вам говорит?

Comment: Я понял перевод ошибки. Но я в форме HTML переменную  "Chislo" объявил  перед созданием файла PHP. Выдалось, как неожиданный иденфикатор. В Интернете такого не нашёл.

Comment: Вы не поняли перевод ошибки. Ошибка как бы намекает Вам на то, что Вы внутрь строки заключенной в двойные кавычки, вставили `$_POST["Chislo"]` и тоже с двойными кавычками. попробуйте например `echo 'Ответ: ' . $_POST['Chislo'];`

Comment: Мне пустоту выдало при вводе "1". Изменения файла сохранил, Apache выключил  и включил, сайт перезагружал.

Comment: Пустота вида `Ответ: ` или просто ничего? `$_POST["Chislo"]` скорее всего приходит в виде строки, а не как int, а Вы проверяете на int. Во-торых, перестаньте ставить везде пробелы, где их не должно быть, после всех атрибутов, в том числе в названии Вашего файла обработчика `3 (8).php`.

Comment: На сайте ни одного символа не видно.  Название файла так и называется "3 (8).php".

Comment: @StackOverflow давайте еще раз. Если на сайте ничего не видно, значит проверка `if(is_int($_POST["Chislo"]))` не прошла. Выше я Вам написал, что то что Вы отпрвляете внутри `$_POST["Chislo"]` -- строка, а не число, так как Вы используете `input type="text"`. То есть, все работает так как у Вас и написано, Вы отправили 1 в виде строки, проверка не прошла и ничего не вывелось. Сделайте просто проверку `if($_POST["Chislo"])` или используйте `input type="number"` либо проверяйте на строку тогда.

Comment: Помогли Ваши 2 способа вместе: " if($_POST["Chislo"]) или используйте input type="number" ",  несколько раз работало input type="text", затем перестало. У кого-то возможно input type="text" сработает. Только единственная беда, что в случае с 0 показывается пустой ответ, где даже слова "Ответ: " нет.

Comment: Ещё, если открыть php файл на сервере, то выдаст ошибку: Warning: Undefined array key "Chislo"... (путь файла php)... on line 3.